# Define variable as database cursor python

Tags: python, pycharm, psycopg2, python-typing

I wrote a module to manage database of my program using psycopg2.

```py
import psycopg2

db_cursor = None


def connect() -> bool:
    global db_cursor
    try:
        db = psycopg2.connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
        db.autocommit = True
        db_cursor = db.cursor()
        logging.info('Connected to database')
        return True
    except psycopg2.Error:
        logging.exception('Error while connecting to database')
        return False


def insert() -> bool:
    global db_cursor
    try:
        db_cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO TABLE ...'
        )
        return True
    except psycopg2.Error:
        logging.exception('Error while adding new entry to database')
        return False

# Other database functions which use 'global db_cursor'...
```

For each `db_cursor.execute()`, PyCharm generates a warning:

> Cannot find reference 'execute' in 'None'

I know it is because I initially set `db_cursor` to `None` and PyCharm doesn't know it is going to be a database cursor object.

The code works without any problems but those warnings are somewhat annoying! How should I write the code so PyCharm knows it is going to be a database cursor and stop those warnings?

I tried to use `variable: type` (PEP 526) syntax but I don't know how to set type as `cursor`.

**UPDATE:** I tried `a = type(db_cursor)` and debugger showed `a` as "psycopg2.extensions.cursor"; however when I write `db_cursor: psycopg2.extensions.cursor` PyCharm shows another warning:

> Cannot find reference 'extensions' in '**init**.py | **init**.py'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I imported `psycopg2.extensions` and defined cursor as `dc_cursor: psycopg2.extensions.cursor` and all warnings suppressed.

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import extensions

dc_cursor: psycopg2.extensions.cursor


def connect() -> bool:
    global db_cursor
    # ...
```